# Can Sove this Error FileNotFoundException please?

Tags: android, android-studio, file, filenotfoundexception

Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\HP\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication9\app\build\intermediates\incremental\packageDebug\tmp\debug\zip-cache\androidResources (Access is denied)

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

// I tried turning off read-only option but still doesn't work

Comment: try deleting  build & .idea folder & re-build again

Comment: Still not working , please help me finding solution , i've been fighting with this error since morning

Comment: When are you  getting this erro ?

Comment: while clicking run

Answer (score 0):

Run your Android Studio as administrator. Maybe your problem will be solved.

Comment: i have tried that one too, but didn't work..